# How type conversion is done in the following code?

Tags: c++, embedded

In the below code, the variable `Speed` is of type `int`. How is it stored in two variables of `char` type? I also don't understand the comment  `// 16 bits - 2 x 8 bits variables`.

Can u explain me with example for the type conversion because when I run the code it shows symbols after type conversion

```
AX12A::turn(unsigned char ID, bool SIDE, int Speed)
{       
     if (SIDE == LEFT)
     {
        char Speed_H,Speed_L;
        Speed_H = Speed >> 8;
        Speed_L = Speed;     // 16 bits - 2 x 8 bits variables
     }
}

main(){
   ax12a.turn(ID,Left,200)
}
```

Comment: It's splitting a 16-bit `int` into 2 8-bit `char`s. Example: `0xABCD -> 0xAB and 0xCD`. See [Bitwise shift operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators)

Comment: The method signature requires `(unsigned char, bool, int)` yet you're calling `(unsigned char, int)`. Have you compiled this code?

Comment: Ax12a.turn(ID,LEFT,200)How would 200 get split into 2 8 bit char?

Comment: [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/141525)

Comment: Shifts all numbers left or right given number if times

Comment: This code uses "sloppy typing", where someone naively use the default types of the language. These types are entirely unsuitable for bitwise arithmetic since they are signed. You must replace `char` with `uint8_t` and `int` with `uint16_t` or similar. Otherwise the program may contain poorly-defined behavior bugs. Also `main(){` has not been valid C for 20 years and never valid C++. Your current source of learning is extremely outdated.

Answer (score 2):

It *seems like* on your platform, a variable of type `int` is stored on 16 bits and a variable of type `char` is stored on 8 bits.

This does not always happen, as the C++ standard does not guarantee the size of these types. I made my assumption based on the code and the comment. Use data types of fixed size, such as the ones described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), to make sure this assumption is always going to be true.

Both `int` and `char` are integral types. When converting from a larger integral type to a smaller integral type (e.g. `int` to `char`), the most significant bits are discarded, and the least significant bits are kept (in this case, you keep the last 8 bits).

Before fully understanding the code, you also need to know about right shift. This simply moves the bits to the right (for the purpose of this answer, it does not matter what is inserted to the right). Therefore, the least significant bit (the rightmost bit) is discarded, every other bit is moved one space to the right. Very similar to division by 10 in the decimal system.

Now, you have your variable `Speed`, which has 16 bits.

```
Speed_H = Speed >> 8;
```

This shifts `Speed` with 8 bits to the right, and then assigns the 8 least significant bits to `Speed_H`. This basically means that you will have in `Speed_H` the 8 most significant bits (the "upper" half of `Speed`).

```
Speed_L = Speed;
```

Simply assigns to `Speed_L` the least significant 8 bits.

The comment basically states that you split a variable of 16 bits into 2 variables of 8 bits, with the first (most significant) 8 bits being stored in `Speed_H` and the last (least significant) 8 bits being stored in `Speed_L`.

Comment: Can u explain me with example for the type conversion because when I run the code it shows symbols after type conversion

Comment: That is expected since the variables are `char`, which are by default displayed as characters. When printing it, print it as decimal (the easiest way is to print `(int)Speed_L` instead of `Speed_L`. But the decimal values might not be that useful in understanding what happens. Hexadecimal would be much more useful. If you print it in hex, you might have something like A1C2 for Speed, which gets split into A1 and C2.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I understand that sizeof(int)  = 2 bytes in your case.

Let us take example as shown below.

int my_var = 200;

my_var is allocated 2 bytes of memory address because datatype is ‘int’.

value assigned to my_var is 200.

Note that 200 decimal = 0x00C8 Hexadecimal = 0000 0000 1100 1000 binary

Higher byte 0000 0000 binary is stored in one of the addresses allocated to my_var
And lower byte 1100 1000 is stored in other address depending on endianness.

To know about endianness, check this link

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/little-and-big-endian-mystery/

In your code :

int Speed = 200;

Speed_H = Speed >> 8;

=>  200 decimal value right shifted 8 times

=>  that means 0000 0000 1100 1000 binary value right shifted by 8 bits

=>  that means Speed_H = 0000 0000 binary

Speed_L = Speed;

=>  Speed_L = 200;

=>  Speed_L = 0000 0000 1100 1000 binary

=>  Speed_L is of type char so it can accommodate only one byte

=>  The value 0000 0000 1100 1000  will be narrowed (in other words "cut-off") to least significant byte and assigned to Speed_L.

=>  Speed_L = 1100 1000 binary = 200 decimal